# React-native dependencies installed independently in android device

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react native. I am facing many issues in React Native.

First: When I installed my app in android emulator or device then I notice the dependencies installed independently. I checked those as:
Open Settings -> Apps & Notifications -> See all XX Apps 
Then I notice all my dependencies installed there.

Second: When I installed my release APK in devices then its working fine. But when I try to install second time on the same device then I am getting an **error: App has not installed**

[image]"

If anyone can help me then please do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the app and installing the new version? for "App not installed" error

Comment: Yes i had uninstalled the app, But after uninstalling the app my dependency packages were still installed. I removed them one by one.